# How to make Samsung multifunction printer work under Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, printing, samsung

Hi how do I set this Samsung CLX 3305FN printer scanner to scan? I can get the printer to work both USB and Network, but simple scan tells me nothing is detected?
Can someone tell me what I need please

Answer (score 3):

Here are the necessary steps I had to perform:

1. Ignore all Samsung Provided CD’s and downloads. They do not work under Oneiric Ocelot (11.10)
2. Add Samsung Unified Driver repository http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/smfpv3.html
3. Install Samsung drivers and libsane-extras
4. Edit sane configuration files

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
   #add the Samsung Unified Driver Repo
   deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra
   ```

   ```
   wget http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg
   sudo apt-key add suldr.gpg
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install samsungmfp-data samsungmfp-driver samsungmfp-network samsungmfp-scanner samsungmfp-configurator-data samsungmfp-configurator-qt4 libsane-extras
   ```

The following sane config files need to be modified (add lines)

```
sudo vim /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf

# Samsung SCX-3400
usb 0x04e8 0x344f

/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules

# Samsung SCX-3400
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="344f", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

The entries above are for the SCX-3400 model. To find the USB ID’s for other models use

```
sane-find-scanner
```

I used **USB ID: vendor=0x04e8 device=0x3456** instead.

Source:

http://www.gaggl.com/2012/04/installing-samsung-multifunction-printer-ubuntu-11-10/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/forum/index.php?topic=131.0

This was the answer that I needed to solve my problem

Comment: My version of Ubuntu is 12.04 32-bit, Put this:                 - edit /etc/sane.d/xerox_mfp.conf to add:
# Samsung CLX-3305
usb 0x04e8 0x3456                                                           

- edit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules to add:                 
# Samsung CLX-3305
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3456", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"

Comment: finally I disconnect and reconnected the usb-cable and the scanner was found immediatly :-)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The link where I found the solution is posted above, also the soultion is copy and pasted right after. Since I am new at this maybe the format is not perfect but the solution works. By the way, by hitting the Enter-button I just wanted a new line, not to send the post. How do I do that(get a new line instead of posting when I hit the ENTER-button)?

Comment: Did you read my comment? It says that **is preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here**. It means that if the website goes KAPUT, we still know what the answer is about.

Comment: @bjorne You should add the information you have posted in comments to your answer by 'editing' it. You should also add a basic overview of the solution in the link to your answer, like Braiam said